# Amount of homomorphisms from $V$ to $S_4$

Tags: abstract-algebra, permutations, group-homomorphism

I am trying to count the amount of homomorphisms from the klein four group to $S_n$, so the homommorphisms $f: V_4\to S_n$.

I think I am almost there, but just wanted to let you guys know my way of reasoning, and if that is correct: the elements of $V_4$ all have order 2 (except the identity). So they all need to go to an element of order 2 in $S_4$, right?

The elements of $S_4$, with order 2, are: (1 2), (1 3), (1 4), (2 3), (2 4), (3 4), (1 2)(3 4), (1 3)(2 4), (1 4)(2 3). So that is 9 elements.

Then I am a bit stuck. Am I at least going in the right direction?

Comment: No, since we need that the product of two of them is the third.

Comment: oh yes of course!

Comment: So how would you go about it @AnginaSeng?

Comment: I'd consider the possible images of $f$.

Comment: @AnginaSeng so now I have the images:
- trivial homomorphism  (everything to the identity)
- $\{(), (1 2), (3 4), (1 2)(3 4)\}$
- $\{(), (1 3), (2 4), (1 3)(2 4)\}$
- $\{(), (1 4), (2 3), (1 4)(2 3)\}$
- $\{(), (1 2)(3 4), (1 3)(2 4), (1 4)(2 3)\}$

Comment: I reckon there are also homomorphisms whose  image has size $2$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Hint:* $V \cong C_2 \times C_2$. Consider the possible homomorphisms $C_2 \to S_4$.

Comment: Ok! Then I get , $ e \mapsto ()$, and then $1$ can map to all elements of order 2, which there are 9 of, and to the identity, so that is 10 possibilities?

Comment: @Josephine, yes, $10$ homomorphisms $C_2 \to S_4$ and so $10 \times 10$ homomorphisms  $ C_2 \times C_2 \to S_4$

Comment: Now I have you here, if I want to get the homomorphisms from $C_2 \times C_2 \to C_4$, can I get this in the same way? So first count the homomorphisms from $C_2 \to C_4$, (2, right?), then the total is $2 *2=4$ ?

Comment: @Josephine, exactly

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: One more question: rthese re only the injective homomorphisms, right? Or not?

Comment: Oh wait,' if I want to count all the injective homomorphisms, then I get 9 * 9 right?